# Is there any "typical" approach to show a proposition about linear programming?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

Consider the feasible sets of  two linear programmings:
$$
\begin{aligned}
& (1) \quad \mathcal{X}\equiv \{x\in \mathbb{R}^K: Ax=b \text{ and } Cx\leq d\}\\
& (2) \quad\mathcal{X}_h\equiv \{x\in \mathbb{R}^K: Ax=b \text{ and } C_hx=d_h \text{ and } C_{-h}x\leq d_{-h}\}
\end{aligned}
$$
where $C=[C_h; C_{-h}]$ and $d=[d_h; d_{-h}]$. Essentially, in (2), I force **some** (not all) of the inequalities in (1) to be equalities.

**Question**: Is there any typical approach used to show that "**if** $\mathcal{X}$ is non-empty, **then** $\mathcal{X}_h$ is non-empty"?

**Thoughts**: I'm not a mathematician, but naively I would suggest to show that:

(a) $\mathcal{X}^*_h\equiv \{x\in \mathbb{R}^K: C_{h}x=d_{h}\}$ is non-empty

(b) $\mathcal{X}^*_h\subseteq \mathcal{X}$.

(a) and (b) seem, however, a bit "definitional" and do not really make the problem any easier. I wonder whether are there  "easier to prove" sufficient conditions that I could use. Is there any well-known "property" that the inequalities $C_h x \leq d_h$ should satisfy in order for the claim to hold?

Comment: Your intuition is correct in that $\mathcal{X}_h$ could be the boundary of $\mathcal{X}$ but you need to be careful. As stated, it is not true. As an example, take a one dimensional case and take the constraint $C_h x \leq  d_h$ as being $-1 \leq x \leq 1$. Even if $\mathcal{X}$ is non empty, $\mathcal{X}_h$ is empty.

Comment: @MarcDinh Thanks, you made me realise my suggestion was wrong. I've rephrased the last part of my post, although I'm far away from understanding what it would be sufficient to prove in order for my claim to be correct.